# How to filter OpenFileDialog to only select 3d file formats

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

So I have this function to import 3d file formats in my application but can't filter the file dialog to only show 3d files. I am using this way of filtering:

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "3D Object (*.STL,*.OBJ,*.FBX,*.COLLADA,*.3DS,*.IGES,*.STEP,*.VRML,*.X3D)|*.STL,*.OBJ,*.FBX,*.COLLADA,*.3DS,*.IGES,*.STEP,*.VRML,*.X3D"
```

So when I am using that kind of filter, the dialog shows nothing even if the current directory contains 3d file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Anyone who hasn't read the relevant documentation should not be posting a question on this site and you clearly didn't read the documentation for the [`OpenFileDialog.Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_Filter) property because, if you had, you wouldn't have needed to ask the question at all. ALWAYS read the documentation first. All you had to do was click the name in code and press *F1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no parentheses, no commas

`OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "3D Object|*.STL;*.OBJ;*.FBX";`

if you have 2 filters or more:

`OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "3D Object|*.STL;*.OBJ;*.FBX" & "|Office Files|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt" & "|All Files|*.*"`

Comment: I just put a parenthesis there to show the accepted 3d files pal. Anyway, I've tried to remove the commas and put semicolon instead and its now working fine :) Thanks Pal!

Comment: Ah ok, well it's up to you to add whatever you want, glad it's working :)

Comment: Yeah pal, hope to help you back soon :) Good day!

Comment: Not much point putting the concatenation operator between two literals.

Comment: Tell that to Microsoft cause my answer is from their site :P